# main thread blocked on SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Till now, happened just once.

I use a third-party library, and it call the function below:

```
- (BOOL) isReachableViaWiFi {

    NSAssert(reachabilityRef, @"isReachableViaWiFi called with NULL reachabilityRef");

    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;
    NetworkStatus status = NotReachable;

    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags)) {
        status = [self networkStatusForFlags: flags];
        return  (ReachableViaWiFi == status);
    }

    return NO;

} // isReachableViaWiFi
```

When I find my UI stopped, I paused the program execution, and every time it stops at `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` line:

[image]

[image]

I'm confused about that. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing on the code you've posted I would say that your problem is that you synchronously call to SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags in main thread. I think there is a big chance that this function pings something on the Internet. If the remote host it tries to ping is not reachable for some reason(you've lost internet connection) you will get ordinary network timeouts which can be really long (30 sec). You will block you main thread (with all the UI) for this time.

So the solution for your problem could be: to call this function on another queue/thread and then pass result to your main thread. By doing this you are not blocking main thread while waiting for some remote host response.

In general you should avoid to run any network interaction code on main thread.

Comment: Thanks. It's called by the third-party library, and the main thread was blocked for more than 1 minute.

Comment: The other thing I can think of is runloop in which network reachability lives. It can be blocked by something or it can be incorrectly set up.

Comment: There is a nice article by Mike Ash - [link](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-06-14-reachability.html). The comments to it are also great, I recommend to read them too.

Answer (score 1):

The Reachability sample demonstrates the asynchronous use of the SCNetworkReachability API. You can use the API synchronously, but do not issue a synchronous check by hostName on the main thread. If the device cannot reach a DNS server or is on a slow network, a synchronous call to the SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags function can block for up to 30 seconds trying to resolve the hostName. If this happens on the main thread, the application watchdog will kill the application after 20 seconds of inactivity.