# AFNetworkReachabilityManager says no network

Tags: ios7, afnetworking-2

I'm confused due to lack of examples, so I did this in my appDelegate's didFinishLaunching:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
bool isThere = [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable];
```

And that always returns false, in spite of the network being there and working.

Two questions:

1) if I'm not looking for changes in status, do I need startMonitoring?

2) is there anything you need to do before reading isReachable? Do you need to wait?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it's too late to answer. If anybody looking for this.

Determining network status requires little time.
So, calling **isReachable** right after startMonitoring will always return **false**.

You can call **isReachable** inside **setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock** ;

```
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
          NSLog(@"status changed");
         //check for isReachable here
    }];
```

Comment: Excellent solution, not too late at all!

Comment: Nice solution ,Thank's

Answer (score 3):

Hey I am very late to post the answer, but when I saw this question I remembered how long I've spent time to get one working code to check if network is available and finally found this code. Connectivity variable is a Bool which will give momentary network status when accessed, use of this code block in a class will give you real time network status. Its in swift hope someone will find it useful.
Thanks

```
func checkNetworkStatus(completion:@escaping (_ connected:Bool) ->())
{
    let reachability = AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared()
    reachability.startMonitoring();
    reachability.setReachabilityStatusChange({ (status) -> Void in

        switch(status) {

        case .unknown:
            self.connectivity = false
            completion(false)

        case .notReachable:
            self.connectivity = false
            completion(false)

        case .reachableViaWWAN:
            self.connectivity = true
            completion(true)

        case .reachableViaWiFi:
            self.connectivity = true
            completion(true)
        }
    })
}
```

This code block can be used in your class as

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.initNetworkMonitoring { (status) in
        // make necessary UI updates
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

isReachable is done by Apple API **SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags**. This is a block call, so AFN call it in a background queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),^{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(self.networkReachability, &flags)) {
        AFPostReachabilityStatusChange(flags, callback);
    }
});
```

If you try https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability you get the result immediately then. But of course it may cause the problem like this, [main thread blocked on SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648972/main-thread-blocked-on-scnetworkreachabilitygetflags)

```
-(BOOL)isReachable
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;  

    if(!SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(self.reachabilityRef, &flags))
        return NO;

    return [self isReachableWithFlags:flags];
}
```